# Ordering under assumptions

Tags: functions, sorting

I have a three-element list which contains inverses of a function `u`, like so:

```
CEs = {(u^(-1))[0.448165 u[10]+0.551835 u[30]],(u^(-1))[0.296264 u[10]+0.703736 u[30]],30}
```

I would now like to obtain the ranking of the elements of this list under the assumption that `u` is strictly increasing but struggle even to understand the output of

```
Ordering@Ordering@CEs
```

, which gives

```
{2, 3, 1}
```

without Mathematica knowing anything about `u`. Could someone explain to me how this ranking comes about and how I might be able to teach Mathematica that `u` is strictly increasing and to order elements under this assumption? In the current case the ordering should be

```
{1, 2, 3}
```

Comment: That explains the ordering Mathematica returns. Anyway I can teach it to sort assuming that `u` is strictly increasing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $ u $ is strictly increasing, then so is $ u^{-1}. $ You don't really care about their values so a representative of strictly increasing functions will preserve the ordering. $  y=x $ is such a function so I am replacing your `u`, `u^(-1)` with `Identity` and the ordering is the desired:

```
CEs = {(u^(-1))[0.448165 u[10] + 0.551835 u[30]], (u^(-1))[
   0.296264 u[10] + 0.703736 u[30]], 30};
CEs /. Thread[{u, u^(-1)} -> Identity] // Ordering
(*{1,2,3}*)
```